# .NET Listview Control Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, listview

I have a form which requires that you filter on 2 variables before the record is displayed.  The year is repeated for each unique visit when you activate the 1st filter. The 2nd filter displays the unique visit.

How do I display the year or any variable once  in my first listview filter and still display the unique items per year as an example in the 2nd listview filter.

C#.Net is the language I'm using in Visual Studio 2005. thanks.

Comment: I'm with alexD.... this question needs alot more detail...

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly your data is something like:

```
2009 uniquevisit
```

And you want it to look like:

```
2009 uniquevisit1
     uniquevisit2
     uniquevisit3
2008 uniquevisit4
2007 uniquevisit5
     uniquevisit6
     uniquevisit7
```

If yes, just make a template and store a global var and on the databinding of the year literal or label check for the year in your global and set the text to blank in your control and if they are not equal set the global and set the text.

Assuming you are binding it to something, it would work kind of like this:

```
int lastYear = 0;
protected void litYourYearControl_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lit = (Literal)(sender);
    string displayText = "";
    int year = (int)(Eval("YourYearField"));
    if (year != lastYear)
    {
        displayText = year.ToString();
        lastYear = year;
    }
    lit.Text = displayText;
}
```

Your question is really confusing but that's my best shot at understanding what your asking :)